# What can be a better way to handle sending response from controller in nodejs project?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

rooms.js -> controller class for rooms endpoint

```
router.get('/:roomid/fight/verify', function(req, res) {
      roomModel.authenticateUserForFight(req.params.roomid, req.query.otp, res);
    });
```

roomModel -> model class for rooms

```
//authenticate user based on otp provided on client side
exports.authenticateUserForFight = function(roomid, otp, res) {
  db.query('select * from room where roomid=?', [roomid], function(error, rows) {
    if (rows.length == 0) {
      console.log("otp does not exist in db for room:" + roomid);
    } else if (rows.length == 1) {
      var otpInDb = rows[0].otp.toString();
      if (otp == otpInDb) {
        console.log("User is authorised");
        res.status(200);
        res.send("User is authorised");
      } else {
        console.log("User is unauthorised");
        res.status(401);
        res.send("User not authorised");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**This piece of code works fine but is there a better way to send response to client instead of passing res object to model class and setting the status and response message there ? The reason i am passing the res object is because doing res.status and res.send in controller is giving issues as the db call is asynchronous. Suggest some better practices to handle these kind of situtations.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. You should not pass the `res` object. Its a debugging nightmare if there is more than one place from where the function can exit. Its far better that the subsequent functions return the value and the controller responds to the status.

You can simply create a callback method which will be called once the async db query is completed. Something like this

```
router.get('/:roomid/fight/verify', function(req, res) {
      const callback = (status, message) => {
        res.status = status
        res.send(message);
      }
      roomModel.authenticateUserForFight(req.params.roomid, req.query.otp, callback);
    });
```

and the main function can just call this function

```
//authenticate user based on otp provided on client side
exports.authenticateUserForFight = function(roomid, otp, callback) {
  db.query('select * from room where roomid=?', [roomid], function(error, rows) {
    if (rows.length == 0) {
      console.log("otp does not exist in db for room:" + roomid);
    } else if (rows.length == 1) {
      var otpInDb = rows[0].otp.toString();
      if (otp == otpInDb) {
        console.log("User is authorised");
        callback(200, 'user authorized');
      } else {
        console.log("User is unauthorised");
        callback(401, 'user not authorized');

      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the updated code

```
if (otp == otpInDb) {
        console.log("User is authorised");
        res.json({
              status:200,
              message:"user authorized"
        })
      } else {
        res.json({
              status:401,
              message:"user not authorized"
        })
      }
```

It is always better to send your response in envelope. and I can see you are using `String`  like queries. Use orm wrapper like [sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) to prevent SQL injection attacks

Comment: currently i am with returning response from model file. Is it possible to somehow move this to controller class ? Do you think returning from model is acceptable ?

Comment: As per my preference, I do not return from model file. Because model defines your schema and it should only have schema nothing else

Comment: Can you suggest some alternate way to return this from controller file. I was unable to return from controller as the db.query is async call and does not wait and passes the control back to controller.